# Bleak-Detector Not Installing

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I need to Install Bleak-Detector for Scan Memory Leaks. I have already installed `Mitproxy 4.0.4`. But Installation of Bleak-Detector Failed. Can Anyone Explain why this happen ?

> chamikaras@Chamikara-S:~$ sudo npm install -g bleak-detector
>   --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root /usr/bin/bleak -> /usr/lib/node_modules/bleak-detector/dist/node/cli/bleak.js
>
> bufferutil@3.0.5 install /usr/lib/node_modules/bleak-detector/node_modules/bufferutil
>   prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
>
> utf-8-validate@4.0.2 install /usr/lib/node_modules/bleak-detector/node_modules/utf-8-validate
>   prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
>
> mitmproxy@2.1.0 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/bleak-detector/node_modules/mitmproxy
>   scripts/install_python_deps.py
>
> mitmproxy-node requires a Python version >= 3.6, but found 3.5 npm
>   ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! mitmproxy@2.1.0
>   postinstall: `scripts/install_python_deps.py` npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the mitmproxy@2.1.0 postinstall script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/chamikara/.npm/_logs/2018-09-06T06_57_46_797Z-debug.log

Reference to Bleak - http://plasma-umass.org/BLeak/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The error message says Python 3.6 or higher is required whereas Python 3.5 is available on your machine. Try installing Python 3.6 and then install Bleak-Detector or you can try installing older version of Bleak-Detector/MitProxy that works with Python 3.5.

Comment: Already Installed Python3.6 but problem is not that.

Comment: @ChamikaraSamarasekara What Error you getting after updating python ?

Comment: No Error Python Updated Successfully.But Mitmproxy installer not recognized python3.6